# How to know redis cache expired or not

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, azure-redis-cache

A user has multiple accounts and when the user selects a particular account, the date should be updated in table. The condition is like, the date should be updated only when the redis cache expires. If the account data comes from redis cache the table should not be updated.

I created a map and put some key value pairs in the map. Key is like accountId and value is the number of times the user accessed the account. I give the condition, if the count, that is no. Of times the user accessed the account, is greater than 1 then I want to check whether the redis cache expired or not. If it expires the I will update the table otherwise not. Help me to know how to update a table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it could help to state which programming language you are using (for any question on here).
Redis doesn't have any functions to perform this...it has CRUD functionality and that's for the most part.
I would suggest you personally write a DateTime data to the cache and as the user interacts with the cache you can check the date or number of interactions.

Been a while since I used Redis, but I hope this help